# jQuery scroll não funciona no chrome no retroceder para página anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, rolamento

Eu tenho este código que funciona bem (basta um scroll para baixo) no firefox e no chrome , mas se a seguir carregar no 'retroceder' do navegador (chrome) ele faz *trigger* logo no *load* da página sem eu fazer **scroll**.
No Html tenho:

```
`<body onunload="">...`
```

js.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

window.scrollTo(0, 0); // ir logo para topo no load da pagina para evitar
                       // que faça trigger à animação sem eu fazer scroll

.......

$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10){
            var href = $('.toWork').attr('href');
            $('#wrapper').animate({
                "margin-top": "-1000px"
            }, 800, function(){
                window.location=href;
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Este comportamento depende do browser e da versão do jQuery que você está utilizando (1.4 e superiores funcionam diferente de versões mais antigas).

Houve [uma discussão sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button) a um tempo atrás no StackOVerflow, não sei se o workaround deles servirá para você, pois a resposta é muito antiga, mas por via das dúvidas, verifique se você está usando a última versão do jQuery.

Comment: Tenho, 1.11.1. Não existe uma maneira de, com código, dar a volta a isso? Com base no código que postei

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você deve estar tentando carregar o jQuery a partir do Google no link:

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"
```

Isso faz com que o Chrome não execute o *script* de uma página não segura em uma página segura.

Quando tive esse problema mudei de `http` para `https` e rodou normal.

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"
```